# Is there a project facet for adding spring libraries to a project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

Everywhere I look I can only see people adding external jars to their Spring MVC web projects when starting a new one. Why isn't there a simple project facet for adding these to a project? I mean, what's the point of creating all these neato eclipse plugins if I can't quickly start a dynamic web project for spring framework without going through this tedious manual process?

Also if I have to download these jars separate of the Spring IDE and core plugins won't I run into problems if the versions become out of sync.

There are project facets for jstl, struts, jsf...etc.. why not spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a package from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html) which contains a Spring [facet](http://blog.symbyo.com/2010/02/build-java-application-with-eclipse.html), but it also contains quite a large amount DB & WebLogic Stuff.

http://blog.symbyo.com/2010/02/build-java-application-with-eclipse.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

MyEclipse for Spring will automatically add all required libraries to Spring MVC, Spring Web Flow, Adobe+Spring, and GWT+Spring web applications.  It definitely saves a lot of time when starting new projects.

Comment: Since MyEclipse is a full IDE I can't accept this one. I need a way to make any eclipse version do this. I have enough eclipse installs as it is. Thanks for the tip though